# Remove all except some elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following page layout:

```
<div id="page-container" class="">
<div id="scroller">
<!-- This page should be removed -->
    <div id="page_1" class="pagina"></div>
<!-- These pages should be kept -->
    <div id="page_2" class="pagina"></div>
    <div id="page_3" class="pagina"></div>
<!-- This is the current page -->
    <div id="page_4" class="pagina"></div>
<!-- These pages should be kept -->
    <div id="page_5" class="pagina"></div>
    <div id="page_6" class="pagina"></div>
<!-- These pages AND everything that follows should be removed -->
    <div id="page_7" class="pagina"></div>
    <div id="page_8" class="pagina"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

I have a function loadPage(pageNr) which loads a specific page and scrolls it into view.

I also have a function that load's two more pages on top, or below the current page depending on the scroll direction.

What I want to achieve now, is that when my loadPage() function is called, I want to keep 2 pages below and before the current page. All other pages should be removed. This is for speed purposes as my app has 748 pages in total.

What I have tried:

```
//Determine which pages on top of current page should be kept
var firstPageToKeep = (pageNr - 2);

//Delete every page on top that should not be kept in memory
for(x=0;x<firstPageToKeep;x++) {
console.log('x: '+x);
     $('#page_'+x).remove();
}

//=================================

//Determine which pages below current page should be kept
var lastPageToKeep = (pageNr + 2);

//Delete every page below current page that should not be kept in memory
for(y=0;y<lastPageToKeep;y++) {
     $('#page_'+y).remove();
}
```

This does remove every page except the current page. I believe I have set the limits of which pages should be deleted and which not. Why is everything deleted except the current page?

Comment: you have 2 `page_7` ids, could be a problem, can't tell without seeing more, but its an id conflict none the less

Comment: Copy/paste problem. Will fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('.pagina').each(function(i, page) {
    if ((i < pageNr - 3) || (i > pageNr + 1)) {
        $(page).remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6NCmR/

Comment: Unfortunately that too removes everything except the current page

Comment: So I've set `pageNr = 4`, than executed my code, and got correct result: pages from 2 to 6.

Comment: But did you try it in the link I gave you? I think something else is messing with your code?

Comment: I see. Thx for clarification. Your code seems to be working fine. Have you tried clicking on a link in the sidebar on my site? That should function your code also

Comment: Looks like there's something interfering. Grrr :) Your code works and I know where to look for now. I'll mark this answer as accepted!

Comment: Good luck with the fixing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$("#scroller").children().not("#id1 #id2 ...").each(function(){//Your code});
```

Answer (score 0):

My quick guess is, that your last for-loop deletes all pages up to lastPageToKeep, keeping only the last pages. You should iterate beginning from lastPageToKeep+1 up to the maximum number of pages.

Nevertheless I'd recommend to you the `:lt` and `:gt` selectors from jQuery!

I made a quick fiddle for you demonstrating the use:
http://jsfiddle.net/d6tZ6/

---

Note: As a side effect this will also remove the neccessity for having an ID for each page.